# Split fasta file based on groups in header information and output as separate files

Tags: python, fasta, bash, awk

I have a fasta file containing the sequence of a gene across different species. In total there are around 900 samples and 12 species. (Each sequences is over multiple lines and longer than 100bp.)

My fasta file looks like:

```
>Species-1-samplenameA
CTATCCTTAAACGCATATCTCGCACAGTAACTCCCCAATATGTGAGCATCTGATGTTGCCCGGGCCGAGTTAGTCTTGTGCTCACGGAACTTATTGTATG
>Species-2-samplenameB
AGTAGTGATTTGAAAGAGTTGTCAGTTAGCTCGTTCAGGTAATGGTTCCTCACACTACGTCAAAATAAGAGAGCGGTCGTGACATTATCCGTGATTTTCT
>Species-3-samplenameC
CACTACTATCAGTACTCACGACTCGATTCTGCCGCAGCCACGTATCGCCAGAAAGCCAGTCAGCATTAAGGAGTGCTCTGGGCAGGACAACTCGCATAGT
>Species-3-samplenameD
GAGAGTTACATGTTCGTTGGGCTCTTCCGACACGAACCTCAGTTGGCCTACATCCTACCTGAGGTCTGTGCCCCGGTGGTGAGAAGTGCGCATTTCGTTC
```

I want to split this file in one fasta file per species.
I think it’s possible to use the awk function for this but I’m stuck. Does anyone have a script/code that might help me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple Biopython solution- iterate over the sequence records, identify the species, open the file handle using append mode to ensure no data is overwritten, and write the record:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

for record in SeqIO.parse("myfile.fa", "fasta"):
    species = record.id.split('_')[0]
    with open(f"{species}.fa", "a") as f:
        SeqIO.write(record, f, "fasta")
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried: 

`from Bio import SeqIO

for record in SeqIO.parse("test.fasta", "fasta"):
    species = record.id.split('Species-')[0]
    with open(f"{species}.fasta", "a") as f:
        SeqIO.write(record, f, "fasta") `


But I got as output every sample in a separate file and not combined all species one in one file.

Comment: @Julie your code on the line `species =` does not match my code, try what I suggested (if your input format is as described)

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake when posting the question, my fasta headers actually look like: 
>Species-1-samplenameA ... I edited my post.

Comment: @Julie `species = '-'.join(record.id.split('-', 2)[:2])`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot.